# Text Search mongodb for field type Number

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have everything working as I need, but I am facing some silly problem with one of the fileds, that it is not showing results...

I have in my model:

```
adSchema.index({title:"text", description:"text", phone:"text", reference:"text"})
```

The search is perfect in title, description and phone, but not reference.

Every field in model are Strings. E.G:

```
  phone:{
    type:String,
    trim:true
  }
```

Onyl it is not, is the one I have problems:

```
  reference: {
    type:Number,
    required:true,
    unique:true
  }
```

Now, it would be a bad idea to change to String.
Please, anyone knows some method to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What sort of query isn't working?

Comment: when i look for reference, doesn't work. I mean, [...] reference:"text"})

Comment: that isn't how a text index works. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html#text

Comment: adSchema.index({title:"text", description:"text", phone:"text", reference:"text"})
title works / description works / phone works / reference doesn't works. I am asking why reference is the only filed(number type) that doesn't work. I have already read doc. Thanks anyway (I think I just need to convert in type: String to make it work...)

Comment: What query doesn't work?

Comment: if I type something it is in [title, description, phone -must be the full phone number to find it-] it works. BUT, if I type the entire reference, i.e 69, it doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide a sample query that isn't working? and a sample document?

Comment: Sure. This works for: title search, description search, phone search and NOT for reference search. Query: 99. Document: {
 "_id" : ObjectId("5e7b3502d9be8a614d0da9d1"),
 "image" : {
  "imgPath" : [
   "uploads/8603c1b41d2808e875ee49bbdf6157fe"
  ]
 },
 "name" : "pepe",
 "title" : "tucano_woo",
 "description" : "aaaaaaaaaa",
 "phone" : "777777777",
 "reference" : 99,
 "__v" : 0
}

Comment: my index: {
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
   "_fts" : "text",
   "_ftsx" : 1
  },
  "name" : "title_text_description_text_phone_text_reference_text",
  "ns" : "myddbb.ads",
  "weights" : {
   "description" : 1,
   "phone" : 1,
   "reference" : 1,
   "title" : 1
  },
  "default_language" : "english",
  "language_override" : "language",
  "textIndexVersion" : 3
 }

Comment: That query isn't doing a text search.  In order to use a text index you need to use the [text operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html#text) in your query.

Comment: Mongo query operators are type sensitive, so if the document has `"reference":"99"`, a query for `"reference":99` will not match.